# My domain name is unrecognized after a couple of hours

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain

I have a domain mydomain.com for example and use freedns service to add an A record and the destination ip to my webserver. If i try to access mydomain.com or put the ip server into the url all works fine. But after a couple of hours, i can't reach the server through my domain name or through my ip.

I try to access mydomain.com and is now working, i access mydomain.com via the ip of my server and still is not working. I go to the cmd and try ping mydomain.com and is working, i ping mydomain.com ip and is working, please tell me what is wrong.

Problem solved, solution: somebody from my network was searching for ip and mac. And after he found the ip and mac he associated on his computer and he had access to the internet and not i. Now i need i way to hide my mac or my ip so that the user cannot see my mac in the program he use. Thanks for all the anserws.

Comment: Most likely, the freeDNS service requires you to 'refresh' your listing every few hours.

Comment: I'll keep hammering on this ancillary point until, well, until people really take it to heart: There is no value at all in obfuscating the domain name in question ("mydomain.com"). DNS is publicly published information. Unless you are using the domain strictly on internal, private networks, hiding the domain only forces those whom you would like to help you to guess at what the problem might be. We can't perform even the most basic of DNS diagnostics. It merely wastes your time and ours.

Comment: @anastrophe: I can imagine his boss not being happy about going extenal with internal problems...

Comment: @BartDeVos, Perhaps, but that really isn't our problem. People come here with their problems, and experts provide answers, free of charge. Obfuscating critical details essentially abuses our goodwill.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a static IP address so you would be better off using a "free static DNS provider" - try putting that term into your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

> But after a couple of hours, i can't reach the server through my
>   domain name or through my ip.

This, together with the fact that you are able to ping the server, tells me that most likely your web server service (not the server itself) is crashing. Restart the service and check the logs to try and find out why it keeps failing.

Comment: Like this: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart? Where can i find the service logs? Do you mean /var/log/apache2/error.log?

Comment: Yes, like that (assuming you are indeed running Apache). Definitely check the Apache error log(s) and also check the messages log.

Comment: I found this in /var/log/apache2/error.log: [Mon Oct 24 19:01:21 2011] [error] [client 65.110.21.234] File does not exist: /var/www/w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:)

Comment: @mjonutz, that's just a file not found while someone was trying to hack your site. Pretty normal stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a daemon to keep the listing updated, when you use a dynamic DNS service.  Check out this guide for example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS

Comment: From your question - are you saying that you can't access the webserver by IP-address either, after a couple of hours?  How do you usually fix this?